How to customize ESLint warning with line and file name on same line?
Here is a screenshot displaying what I want to avoid. Currently all my ESLint warnings look like this, where the line number is on a separate line to the file name; it's therefore not possible to quickly navigate to the said location. I must first go to the file then manually find the line / character.

Instead, I would like to click on the filename + line to directly go to the warning in VSCode.
I would like the warning to be something like: "src/App.tsx:1:17" which would allow me to click on the name + line going directly to the issue.
Is it possible to customize the output to allow me to quickly navigate to the location?

are you running eslint via commandline? via task in tasks.json? in any case, terminal link detection should cover this. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminalContrib/links/browser/terminalMultiLineLinkDetector.ts#L33... if it's not working, I'd suggest to file an issue ticket with a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. If you do, please add a link here to your issue ticket. As for the output format options of eslint itself, see https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/formatters/

@starball Right! Thanks for the tips and links. I'm running eslint via CRA (Create React App), so when I 'npm start', eslint provides the warnings.  Following the links you provided did not help despite being promising. Perhaps there's a way to modify the eslintConfig in my package.json file to change the output style?

these warning messages are printed in VS Code's integrated terminal, right? can you please paste some sample text from it into your question post? if it's printed into VS Code's integrated terminal, again, I suggest raising an issue ticket (bug).

@starball Yes it is from VScode integrated terminal; the screenshot provided is from VSCode terminal. I will raise a bug ticket (eventually) and link it here.
